# Scroll absolute element in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I use jquery ui in my project and make a dialog box using dialog widget.
In my dialog I create a div with test class. When I scroll the parent of created div, the div not scroll and behavior like fixed position.
How can resolve this problam? 
Thanks so much

this is my php and html code :

```
<div id="second_step-turn">

            <table width="700"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="second-step-tbl">
    <thead id="daily_events_tbl_thead"><tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr></thead>
<tbody id="second-step-tbl-tbody" >
    <input id="startX" type="hidden" />
    <input id="startY" type="hidden" />
    <input id="endX" type="hidden" />
    <input id="endY" type="hidden" />

<?php for($i =0;$i< 24;$i++):
    ($i< 10) ? $j = '0'.$i :$j =  $i;
 ?>
<tr title="<?php echo $j.':00-'.$j.':15'; ?>" >
  <td  class="hour first-tr-in-hour"><?php echo $j.' : 00'   ?></td>
  <td  class="turn-options-td first-tr-in-hour">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="light-border-color" title="<?php echo $j.':15-'.$j.':30'; ?>">
  <td  class="hour">&nbsp;</td>
  <td  class="turn-options-td" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="light-border-color" title="<?php echo $j.':30-'.$j.':45'; ?>">
  <td  class="hour">&nbsp;</td>
  <td  class="turn-options-td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="light-border-color" title="<?php echo $j.':45-'.($j+1).':00'; ?>">
  <td  class="hour">&nbsp;</td>
 <td  class="turn-options-td" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
</tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

and my css :

```
.set-nobat<br/>
{<br/>
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  margin-right:100px;
  width:600px;
  opacity:0.3;
  background:#C0F3C5;
}
```

and my js and jquery:

```
   $(function(){
     $("#second-step-tbl-tbody").mousedown(function(e){
          var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
          var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left);
          var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top);
          document.getElementById('startX').value = relativeXPosition;
          document.getElementById('startY').value = relativeYPosition;
   });

  $("#second-step-tbl-tbody").mouseup(function(e){
     var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
     var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left);
     var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top);
     document.getElementById('endX').value = relativeXPosition;
     document.getElementById('endY').value = relativeYPosition;
     createView();
 });
})
```

```
 function createView()
 {
   var startY = document.getElementById('startY').value
  var endY = document.getElementById('endY').value
parentPos=$("#second-step-tbl-tbody").offset();
var margin_top = parseInt(startY);
var height = parseInt(endY) - parseInt(startY);
var style = 'height:'+height+'px;margin-top:'+margin_top+'px;';
var html = '<div class = "set-nobat" style="'+style+'"></div>';
$("#daily_events_tbl_thead").after(html);
 }
```

Comment: Please share some of your code.. e.g. HTML, CSS, Javascript

Comment: position: absolute; will never scroll. Don't use that, find another solution, and it will work.